# Inserting unsigned 64-bit number into BigInt MySQL column using Java and JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, unsigned

I searched for answer to this question and only found vague answers. Here is the problem:
I have a sample table in MySQL:
mytable
time Timestamp
data BigInt(20) unsigned

Data field is chosen so that it can take in 2^64 max value: 18446744073709551616 (20 digits and hence BigInt(20)).

I have a csv file which contains unsigned 64-bit integers.

Now I am using Java and JDBC to insert this data and running into issues because Java does not have unsigned long. So I tried just passing string - but it fails.

```
st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO pawan_table (mytime, data) VALUES(?, ?)");
st.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(86400000+i*1000));
st.setString(2, "18446744073709551616");
st.execute();
```

I also tried BigInteger class in Java - but JDBC does not have a method which takes that type. I can only convert BigInteger to "long" which is signed and that is not what I want. For example:

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(string_from_csv_file);
st.setLong(2, bi.longValue());
```

Interesting thing is that MySQL Workbench can insert this data - but it is written in c#! and I need to write my code in Java!

How do Java programmers insert unsigned 64-bit number in MySQL BigInt(20) column?

Comment: Have you tried using `st.setLong(2, 18446744073709551616L);`?

Comment: That will give a Java compilation error as it is bigger than LONG_MAX. I just tested it and it does give compilation error.

Comment: Well then, you can't do it using Java.

Answer (score 4):

So here is the solution:

If you do not use prepare statement and are just inserting using a string SQL statement, you have nothing to worry about because JDBC simply moves your statement to MySQL server and MySQL server can correctly parse the string to unsigned 64 number (BigInt-20).

If you use a prepare statement, then you are in trouble. If you do:

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("18446744073709551615"); // max unsigned 64-bit number
statement.setObject(2, bi, Types.BIGINT);
statement.execute();
```

you will get an MySqlDataTruncation exception because JDBC wants to truncate this to signed long.

If you do:

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(new Long(Long.MAX_VALUE).toString());
statement.setObject(2, bi, Types.BIGINT);
statement.execute();
```

This will work because the value is within Java's signed long.

So workaround which always works is:

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("18446744073709551615"); // max unsigned 64-bit number
statement.setString(2, bi.toString());
statement.execute();
```

You end up passing the data as a string and let MySQL server parse it properly.

Someone should fix the JDBC driver because unsigned 64-bit numbers keep coming up in a lot of statistical applications.

Comment: In your question you said that `statement.setString(2, "18446744073709551616");` failed. How is that different to `statement.setString(2, bi.toString())`? Could you show what `bi.toString` returns? I'd be interested to see what the difference is, because it's very strange that this form works.

Comment: As of now, I am getting a `com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of range value for column '<column_name>' at row 1` error with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve this using `PreparedStatement.setObject`. There is a variant that accepts an argument specifying the type of the value: you could pass in a `BigInteger` and `java.sql.Types.BIGINT` and see if that works.

If that fails, then you could create a helper class that implements `SQLData` and pass that to `setObject`.

Disclaimer: I have not tried any of this; it's based off a quick look at the javadocs.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This solution does not work because JDBC driver tries to convert the value to "long" which is signed. I will post the solutions which work and which do not work.

Answer (score 0):

This works with the MySQL backend if the datatype is BIGINT UNSIGNED.

Storing the number works this way:

```
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Speeds (downSpeed) VALUES (?)");
statement.setObject(1, spd.downSpeed, Types.BIGINT);
```

Retrieving works with a raw getObject() call:

```
BigInteger downSpeed = (BigInteger) rs.getObject("downSpeed");
```

I tried using `rs.getObject("downSpeed",BigInteger.class)` but this gave me an unsupported conversion error.

Note the the biggest number that can be stored in the BIGINT UNSIGNED type is 1.8 *10^9.  See here: [MySQL DataTypes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html)