# Can Java's Long hold an SQL BIGINT(20) value?

Tags: java, sql, bigint

I have a table in an SQL database where the values' data type is `BIGINT(20)`, and I need to get those data to my logic in Java for processing.

**What should be the appropriate *data type* in Java to store the `BIGINT(20)` value returned ?**

I thought of using `Long`, but there is `BigInteger` also, can't figure out what is good or suitable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240049/inserting-unsigned-64-bit-number-into-bigint-mysql-column-using-java-and-jdbc

Comment: 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 bigint(20) max value. 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 long max value.

Comment: MySQL has both signed and unsigned bigints(20). That answer is the unsigned one.

Answer (score 12):

MySQL BIGINT: min value (-2^63), max value (2^63-1). Maximum unsigned value (2^64-1).
*https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html*

Java Long: min value (-2^63), max value (2^63-1). Maximum unsigned value (2^64-1).
*https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html*

**So, these two types are the same size :)**

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the database server. A Java `long` is always implemented as 8 bytes since it is part of the standard.

On MSSQL, the `bigint` type is 8 bytes, so it is a perfect match.

Answer (score 1):

Long is perfect  mapping for big Int of database

Answer (score 1):

The BIGINT type is not part of the SQL standard, so there is no guarantee that it will work the same in all databases. However, at least MSSQL, MySQL, Oracle, Postgresql, and IBM DB2 agree that it uses 8 bytes (where most are signed, but in DB2 it's an unsigned 63-bit value ).

Since a Java Long is also 64 bits, it should work fine. Since longs are a lot faster than BigIntegers, so you should almost certainly use a long.

Comment: So what if we want to store an actual BigInteger in the db table ? then what type should we use. btw thank you for your answer.