# Issue with UNSIGNED BIGINT of MySQL while fetching using JDBC client

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

As per [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html), the maximum value for **Unsinged Bigint** = 18446744073709551615

I inserted a value 9223372036854776900 (*far lower than max limit*) in an unsinged Bigint column.

***No error is shown.***

When I tried to access it programmatically  via JDBC client, I got exception:

> **com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLDataException: '9223372036854776900' in column '10' is outside valid range for the datatype BIGINT.**
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1026)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.throwRangeException(ResultSetImpl.java:7964)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.parseLongAsDouble(ResultSetImpl.java:7248)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getLong(ResultSetImpl.java:2946)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getLong(ResultSetImpl.java:2911)

---

**MySQL version** :  5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Comment: Which version of MySQL, JDBC driver, Java?

Comment: @phn **5.1**. Could this be a culprit here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by the stack trace, I was able to recreate your issue when I tried to use `ResultSet#getLong`

```java
Long l = rs.getLong(1);
```

because the stored value, 9223372036854776900, is larger than the maximum value for a (signed) `Long` in Java: 9223372036854775807.

However, I was able to successfully retrieve the value as a BigDecimal using

```java
java.math.BigDecimal bd = rs.getBigDecimal(1);
```

or as BigInteger using

```java
java.math.BigInteger bi = (java.math.BigInteger) rs.getObject(1);
```

Comment: Evidently as the OP indeed calls `getLong`. Actually an error that is very nice.

Answer (score 3):

You're finding your response in the following table of website http://www.mysqlab.net/knowledge/kb/detail/topic/java/id/4929

> Table A.2. Unsigned Types Mapping
>
> ```
>     Data TypeJava Type 
>     TINYINT UNSIGNED      java.lang.Integer
>     SMALLINT UNSIGNED     java.lang.Integer
>     MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED    java.lang.Long
>     INT UNSIGNED          java.lang.Long
>     BIGINT UNSIGNED       java.math.BigInteger
> ```
>
> Note: Before MySQL
>   Connector/J 3.1.3, BIGINT UNSIGNED was mapped to java.math.BigDecimal.

Answer (score 1):

Max value of BIGINT is 9223372036854775807.

From the Oracle documentation ([Mapping SQL and Java Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html))

> 8.3.7 BIGINT The JDBC type BIGINT represents a 64-bit signed integer value between -9223372036854775808 and 9223372036854775807.
>
> The corresponding SQL type BIGINT is a nonstandard extension to SQL.
>   In practice the SQL BIGINT type is not yet currently implemented by
>   any of the major databases, and we recommend that its use be avoided
>   in code that is intended to be portable.
>
> The recommended Java mapping for the BIGINT type is as a Java long.

There is a solution posted to another question that might be useful you: [Inserting unsigned 64-bit number into BigInt MySQL column using Java and JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240049/inserting-unsigned-64-bit-number-into-bigint-mysql-column-using-java-and-jdbc)