# Correct way to use Java Prepared Statement with Unsigned Integer

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, unsigned-integer

I have a foreign key column in my table that holds an `unsigned integer` value. I want to add a new value to this column, but I don't know how java will deal with this `unsigned` value, since java doesn't have native unsigned values.

If I do:

```
preparedStatement.setInt(2, myInt);
```

Will the Database convert this `signed int` to it's `unsigned` value automatically? Or will it throw an error saying that those are incompatible types? Should I step up and use a `long` like:

```
preparedStatement.setLong(2, myLong);
```

Or will this throw an exception as well, because the Database is not using `BIGINT`?

I am using MySQL and I just want to avoid surprises in the future as my table records grow.

Comment: Did you try to implement both approaches and see what happens? :)

Comment: I thought about it, but I tried to google it first and I didn't find anything on this, so I thought it would be a lot more useful if this answer was properly documented, saving future people time.

Comment: @mFeinstein I agree on that! It is not forbidden to create a question and answering it. So you could have tried and create the question matching the test ;-) (If it fails, create a question that ask why and answer because it doesn't support it with example and source, if no other post can be found of course...)

Comment: Well, I could create the question, test it, and answer it, but that's a one case scenario that happened to work for me on the way I set the test... I am not a specialist on this, maybe there are some traps to avoid, maybe MySQL behaves in one way and SQL Server in another, I don't know, that's why I come here, so a specialist can show me all the details I surely would miss.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting unsigned 64-bit number into BigInt MySQL column using Java and JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240049/inserting-unsigned-64-bit-number-into-bigint-mysql-column-using-java-and-jdbc)

Answer (score 2):

> maybe MySQL behaves in one way and SQL Server in another

Leaving aside the fact that SQL Server does not have unsigned integers, your instincts are correct that signed ⇄ unsigned behaviour could very well depend on the implementation of the particular JDBC driver being used. Therefore, the general answer you seek is really "too broad" because it could potentially require a description of implementation-specific details for all of the JDBC drivers whose databases support unsigned integer columns.

So, as suggested in the comments to the question, your best bet for MySQL (or any other particular JDBC driver) would be to

1. see if the JDBC specification itself defines the required behaviour (unlikely),
2. check your JDBC driver documentation for their definitive answer, or
3. test your desired configuration to see if it behaves in a way that will suit your needs.

Comment: See, that's why I wanted a specialist opinion... Now I learned things are not so simple as I thought, and if I tested this myself I could conclude the test behavior would be true forever, even on other databases I use in the future... Now I know I have to be careful every time